# Showing specific values on x or y axes

Tags: matlab, plot

```
a=[1 2 7 5 4 6]
t=0:2:10

plot(t,a);
```

[image]

I want that in the plot on x axis only values : 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10  (as per t=0:2:10 in the code) should be depicted on the time axis unlike the above which shows all values. How do I do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are the xticks, set them like this:

```
set(gca,'Xtick',0:2:10);
```

If you want to hide the yticks:

```
set(gca,'Ytick',[]);
```